# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied in Curl Request

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, postman

I am stuck at a point where the simple URL is working fine in a browser and postman but its not working in Curl called from a PHP code. I am not getting a clue what's going wrong. Even the php code generated from postman is not working.

My sample URL looks like

`https://example.com/WebService/visitorinput.asmx/AddVisitor?CallFromNumber=987xxxxxxx&CallToNumber=886xxxxxxx&CallDateTime=2024-01-10%2018%3A32%3A10&CallType=Missed%20Call&Notes=This%20is%20test%20entry`

While the generated postman code is

```
<?php 

$variables = array(
    "CallFromNumber" => "987xxxxxxx",
    "CallToNumber"   => "886xxxxxxx",
    "CallDateTime"   => "2024-01-10 18:32:10",
    "CallType"       => "Missed Call",
    "Notes"          => "This is test entry",
);

$curl = curl_init();

$url = 'https://example.com/WebService/visitorinput.asmx/AddVisitor?'. http_build_query( $variables ) ; 

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip, deflate, br', // Either I add or not result is same
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [ // Tried to add this header but its same as before
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
  ] 
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

url_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

The requested URL is a web service provided by a different team which built in ASP.net and is working in Postman. In Curl I am getting "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." while in Postman it's a json response

Comment: You appear to be calling `curl_exec` twice - is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Also you have `http_uild_query` guessing that should be `http_build_query`, and `url_close` guessing that should be `curl_close`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Sanjay 403 means that you're trying to access a resource that is restricted to only a specific person/ID/token. Double-check if you have defined any authorization token in postman or any environment variable for the bearer token or any ID.

Comment: _"a web service provided by a different team"_ - so still something "in-house" then, within the same company(?) ... so the quickest way to get clarity, would probably be to ask them about the issue, no?

Comment: At least there are many unbelievable spelling errors in the code in this question, which makes me suspect that the issue is caused by your own carelessness.

Comment: @RobEyre My bad its not in code. I pasted here twice. Thanks for informing.

Comment: @CBroe The webservice provided by different company. And they simply saying check the postman it is working there.

Comment: Are your successful test in postman, and your attempt with PHP/cURL, running on the same machine / sending the request from the same IP address?

Comment: Your curl request has no options set for negotiating SSL connections - that could well be a factor in causing failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort it out by passing user agent in header. Complete request look like this

```
<?php 

$curl = curl_init();

$url = 'https://example.com/WebService/visitorinput.asmx/AddVisitor?' . http_build_query($variables);
register_log( "url: ". print_r( $url, true ) );

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip, deflate, br',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.15) Gecko/20080623 Firefox/2.0.0.15'
]
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Firstly, please add some content to explain why this can solve the OP's question. Although I don't think this can solve it, because the server returned 403, which means the certificate verification has been successful. Additionally, this is not a recommended solution as it is very unsafe.

Comment: Sorry for trying to be helpful